# Xcode 7.0 strange issue with NSMutableArray and NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7

I encountered a strange issue after installing Xcode 7. Certain collections like `NSMutableDictionary` and `NSMutableArray` during debugging shows the collection to be [0] once we place the cursor over the collection. But if we print the collection in console using "po" the value seems to be right there.
Any one here knows what is going on with Xcode.
I have attached images of my Xcode.[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked that you run the project as debug and not release ?

Comment: It's because you aren't using a fixed-width font.

Comment: I just checked.It's in debug mode

Comment: @Droppy - Could you elaborate please....

Comment: Check optimization level settings for Debug in Build Settings section.

Comment: I have :Debug - None and Release - Fastest,Smallest.... --for Optimisation Level

Comment: Checked with other optimisation levels as well... Issue persists.

Comment: I've seen several little "po" issues like this ever since Swift 1.0.  Interestingly enough, it has not improved a lot during this past year with regards to issues like these.

Comment: I resolved this issue for the time being by restarting the machine and starting everything from scratch.Not sure when this issue will reappear again...